# JBoss AS7 sharing multicast address when using clustering with standalone-ha.xml

Tags: jboss7.x, multicast

I am using standalone-ha.xml to cluster JBoss 7.1.1.Final.

Can I use the same multicast address for all the sockets? I.e. jgroups-diagnostics, jgroups-mping, jgroups-udp, modcluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes definitely. Simply need to use unique ports for each different service. I.e. jgroups-diagnostics, jgroups-mping, jgroups-udp, modcluster?